# streamreader not reading from textfilewithin the project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, path, streamreader

I am using the streamreader to read from a file in the project..

```
StreamReader stRead = new StreamReader("textfile.txt");

        while (!stRead.EndOfStream)
        {
            CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(stRead.ReadLine());
        }
```

but i get an error:

> Could not find file 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\textfile.txt'.

whereas the textfile is in my bin folder of the project.

C:\Users\xyz\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\bin\testfile.txt

If i use this path it works but i dont want to use the complete path...

Is there a way to do this???

thanks

how do i store the path as a reference in web.config file????

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400928/c-opening-file-in-a-solution

Comment: i am not able to understand that.. also it is not answered.
and my error message is different..

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the asp.net tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you must use

```
StreamReader stRead = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/textfile.txt"));
```

to resolve the physical position of your file, supposing it's placed in the root of your project.

Answer (score 1):

I would try the project root directory,
otherwise, define the path prefix in a configuration file like your web.config, 
that way if you're worried about path changes it isn't hard-coded

Comment: Depending on what kind of environment you're going to deploy your app on, it might be easier to do something like Tanathos mentioned above,
Otherwise you can put a key in your web.config (xml file) in the appSettings add a key like
<add key="Your path" value="C:\whereever">

Then reference it in your code like string fullpath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Your Path"] + "\filename.txt"; 

Using this style can be convenient if you map different paths in yoru web.config's, or you have to deal with certain permission setups on different deployment environments