# How to include a document in my C# project?

Tags: c#

Ok so i have an html document that i reference in my visual studio 2010 C# application that i need for the application to continue.

here is come code

```
string template = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("template.html");
```

the `template.html` file is currently in my debug directory and I want to be able to have it included if possible in the exe so the user doesnt need to have a copy of the html file for my application to run ...any ideas on how to tackle this

Comment: Do they have to be able to see it as a physical file or could it be embedded in the exe?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexdan/archive/2007/12/19/loading-embedded-resources-in-c-using-getmanifestresourcestream.aspx

Comment: You can also put it in your Project and make it Content, Copy Always. This will always put it in the output directory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# opening file in a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400928/c-sharp-opening-file-in-a-solution)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to right click on the file and make it an embedded resource.

[image]

Then you can access your file with the below code:

```
using (Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                               .GetManifestResourceStream("template.html"))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

more info at :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: so this wont work anymore string template = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("template.html");

Comment: no it won't work anymore as the file won't physically exist at that location -  it will be embedded in the assembly at compile time

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the html file in Solution Explorer -> Properties -> Set Content Type as [Embedded Resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2c9s1d7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

UPDATE:
You can access it through {ProjectBaseNameSpace}.Properties.Resources.{ResourceName}

Comment: do i still access it the same way

Comment: Edited my answer above : Take a look at this tutorial if needed http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3089/Understanding-Embedded-Resources-in-Visual-Studio

Answer (score 1):

Make it an [Embedded Resource](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292).

Comment: do i still access it the same way

Answer (score 1):

Include your file in project and set "Embedded Resource" under build action

and then you can access that resource, here is the example how :

```
Assembly asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
string resourcePath = ".Templates.ActivationEmailTemplate.html";
Stream stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(asm.GetName().Name + resourcePath);
```

note that my ActivationEmailTemplate.html is in the folder "Templates"

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:
[How to embed and access resources by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292)